# SQL AVG on Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count, average

I got two tables that are connected by `Computer_ID`.

First one is `Computer_ID`, `Brand`, `Country` which contains computers, their brand and their origin country.

The second table contains information about the CPU: `Computer_ID`, `CPU_Manufacture`

**Please notice that each computer can have multiple CPUs**

I want to get, for each country, the average number of **Intel**'s CPUs for a computer which its brand is `Dell`

I expect a result like this:

```
Country      |Avg CPUs
United-States|2.5
Canada       |3.2
```

Example data from `Computers` table:

```
Computer_ID|Brand|Country
1          |Dell  |United-States
2          |Lenovo|United-States
3          |Lenovo|United-States
4          |Lenovo|United-States
5          |HP    |United-States
6          |Dell  |Canada
7          |Dell  |Canada
```

Example data from `CPU` table:

```
Computer_ID|CPU_Manufacture
1          |Intel
1          |Intel
2          |Intel
2          |AMD
2          |AMD
3          |AMD
4          |AMD
4          |Intel
```

This is how I'm counting how many CPU's made by Intel each country got:

```
SELECT COMPUTERS.NATIVE_COUNTRY, COUNT(*) FROM COMPUTERS
INNER JOIN CPUS ON CPUS.COMPUTER_ID = COMPUTERS.COMPUTER_ID AND CPUS.MANUFACTURE = 'Intel'              
GROUP BY COMPUTERS.NATIVE_COUNTRY;
```

now basically I need to divide each `COUNT` by the amount of `Dell computers` for each country.

Answer (score 0):

simply add a having clause

`SELECT COMPUTERS.NATIVE_COUNTRY, COUNT(*) FROM COMPUTERS
INNER JOIN CPUS ON CPUS.COMPUTER_ID = COMPUTERS.COMPUTER_ID AND CPUS.MANUFACTURE = 'Intel' GROUP BY COMPUTERS.NATIVE_COUNTRY HAVING COMPUTERS.BRAND = 'DELL';`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly . . .

```
SELECT c.NATIVE_COUNTRY, COUNT(*),
       AVG(CASE WHEN c.BRAND = 'Dell' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) as dell_avg
FROM COMPUTERS c LEFT JOIN
     CPUS cp
     ON cp.COMPUTER_ID = c.COMPUTER_ID AND cp.MANUFACTURE = 'Intel'              
GROUP BY c.NATIVE_COUNTRY;
```

Comment: This is almost the correct answer, but in case a computer got no cpus I want to count it as 0 cpus but still increase the amount of computers. What I mean is that it is possible that some computer_id won't even be in the CPUs table.

Comment: @LiaPopa . . . A `LEFT JOIN` probably does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work as you want:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Country,[Computers]=COUNT(*) FROM Computers com
    WHERE Brand = 'Dell'
    GROUP BY Country
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT Country,Cores=COUNT(*) FROM Computers com
    JOIN CPU cpu ON com.Computer_ID=cpu.Computer_ID
    WHERE CPU_Manufacture='Intel'
    GROUP BY Country
)
SELECT cte.Country,[Cores per computer]=ISNULL(Cores,0)*1./Computers
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN cte2 ON cte.Country=cte2.Country
```